# How to add percent and remained time of download by aria2c via Sysmonitor Indicator?

Tags: scripts, indicator, download-manager

Is it possible to add download progress bar aria2c/wget to panel, especially the percent and remained time of download by [this appindicator](https://github.com/fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor) or sth else?!

I mean when you run aria2c to download a file in a terminal emulator such as gnome-terminal (and then minimize it), the progress of download be in front of your eyes in top panel :)

Comment: @fossfreedom, you're invited :)

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure there isn't an indicator for aria2. You can however integrate aria2 with uGet and get an indicator. The uGet indicator doesn't have a progress bar but it does have indication of currently downloading and completion.

http://uGetdm.com